# How can I best learn SiteMinder? Was handed a site that integrates with it, and need to maintain it

Tags: asp.net-membership, single-sign-on, siteminder

We have SiteMinder configured in our environment and I've been given an ASP.NET website to support.

Where do I begin to learn SiteMinder?  I have some background in ADFS, but need to translate my skills to this product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the bookshelf documentation on [support.ca.com](http://support.ca.com)

CA Education also offers some courses and new certifications, but you can probably learn just as well through the docs.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading all the documentation.
I would also recommend purchasing a VMWare workstation license and getting an isolated installation of SiteMinder, AD, the POlicy Server and a protected web server on the VM.  that will give you a nice sandbox on which to play, just remember to take a snapshot after you get it all installed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of purchasing VMWare, you can use Oracle VirtualBox to run a CentOS VM (CentOS essentially the free version of RedHat).

The newest versions of SiteMinder (CA Single Sign On) only support RedHat Linux and Microsoft Windows.